# What is the name of this plant which has roots on its stem?

Tags: identification

I've had this plant for a long time. It was a gift and I never knew exactly what it was. It had its good times and its bad times and gave flowers a few times, which are little pink to purple and bell-shaped. Now almost all of it rotted, so I transplanted the two parts which were still fine. Happily the plant formed roots on its stem (check the second picture). Due to the thick leaves I would think it's a succulent, but I do not find any picture with leaves similar to this one.

Now, I would like to check how to take care of it best (probably I gave it too much water), but therefore I need to know what species it is.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a [Kalanchoe](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kalanchoe), possibly Kalanchoe uniflora.  It is very hard to tell the exact species as there are thousands of cultivars. 
Fortunately the care is the same for most of the common ones:

- bright, sunny locations, especially in the summer growing season. During the winter, consider a south-facing window.
- water moderately throughout the summer and reduce watering in the winter. Let the soil surface dry out between watering. In the winter let the plant get drier. Watch out for signs of too much water by observing the fleshy leaves..
- they like warm surroundings. Do not let fall below 55 deg Fah or about 12 deg Celsius.
- an ordinary potting soil mix is fine but I prefer one that is a bit more free draining.  Add more perlite to accomplish this.

Edit:sometimes the signs of over watering are:

- bacterial infections such as spots or sunken lesions on the leaves
- soil is wet but the leaves are limp and dry because the roots have rotted

Comment: The Kalanchoe thanks you! Signs of too much water would be rupture?